# autocomplete in a file without project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans-plugins

Is it possible to activate full autocompletion without having the file added to a project?
Maybe with a plugin or any another modification?

I installed the plugin "remote file systems" for netbeans 6.9.1 (php) 
(http://www.stoehrer.net/downloads/remotefs/nb-remotefs-0.1.3.zip) to access my linux server over ssh on my windows machine.
Autocompletion doesn't work with it - the files have to be in a netbeans project :(

I also tried the mounting tool "dokan" but sometimes it destroys a file when I save.
Other mounting tools work less well or just show my home folder.

Sorry for my english and thx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

coudnt solve the problem that way

so i used samba and add the files to a netbeans project

wasnt easy because for some reason 
i have to use the ip path ("\\192.168.xx.xxx" and type my smbuser and the password)
to map the drive in windows

on my other pc i didnt need that. dont know why

bye guys

Comment: Bad to hear that! +1 For saving me the time of looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug, or as they have called it, the [umbrella issue #135222](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=135222), to aggregate requests and ideas regarding how to

> Improve support for editing files that do not belong to a project.

I have just added the suggestion of [somehow allowing to define a classpath for files that don't belong to any project](http://wiki.netbeans.org/EditingFilesOutsideOfProject#UI). I hope I can soon update this answer with a "there is a better way..." ;-)